# How to use \ in a string in PHP?

Tags: php

i want to use \ in a string,like

```
public function log($logLevel,$msg){
    $class=substr(__CLASS__,strpos(__CLASS__,'\'));
    $filPath=$class."-log.txt";
    file_put_contents($filPath,$logLevel." : ".$msg.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

But this is giving me error. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Backslashes in PHP are interpreted as the start of an escape character. Your sequence, `'\'`, starts a string and **escapes** the second `'` instead of using it to close the string. Use two backslashes (`\\`) to escape the first backslash instead of escaping your quote.

See [Escape sequences](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) and [the documentation for strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax).

Comment: ...as in `$class=substr(__CLASS__,strpos(__CLASS__,'\\'));`